# Tkinter <enter> and <leave> Events Not Working Properly

Tags: python, tkinter

Forgive me in advance for my code, but I'm simply making this for friend of mine to automatically populate a GUI interface with song information, channel information for each song, and things such as images attached to the songs. Right now I'm only scraping from a playlist on Youtube and a playlist on Soundcloud. I have all of that properly working, but me being new to frontend development left me in a horrible spot to make a decent application for him. I had a lot in mind that I could have done, but now I'm simply creating buttons with each song title as the text. [Here is an image of my progress.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ4CD.jpg) I still have to find a way to attach each image to each button for the on_enter event, but that is for later on. As you can see, I have a on_leave function commented out. I was using that to delete the self.image_window each time I left a button. Problem is even a minuscule amount of mouse movement would cause the window to be delete and recreated dozens of times. How do I make it static so when I am hovering over a button it doesn't spam create/delete the window?

Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *
import json
import os
import webbrowser


class GUIPopulator(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.configure(bg='PeachPuff2')
        self.columnconfigure(20, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(30, weight=1)
        self.curtab = None
        self.tabs = {}
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.column = 0
        self.row = 0

    def on_enter(self, event):

        self.image_window = Toplevel(self)
        self.img_path = os.getcwd() + '/Rotating_earth_(large).gif'
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.img_path)

        #self.image_window.minsize(width=200, height=250)
        self.image_window.title("Preview")
        canvas = Canvas(self.image_window, width=200, height=200)
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=self.img)
    #def on_leave(self, enter):



    def addTab(self, id):
        tabslen = len(self.tabs)

        tab = {}
        if self.row < 30:
            btn = Button(self, text=id,highlightbackground='PeachPuff2' ,command=lambda: self.raiseTab(id))

            btn.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column, sticky=W+E)

            btn.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)

            #btn.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)


            tab['id']=id
            tab['btn']=btn



            self.tabs[tabslen] = tab
            self.raiseTab(id)
            self.row +=1
        else:
            self.row = 0
            self.column +=1
            btn = Button(self, text=id,highlightbackground='PeachPuff2' ,command=lambda: self.raiseTab(id))

            btn.grid(row=self.row, column=self.column, sticky=W+E)

            tab['id']=id
            tab['btn']=btn

            self.tabs[tabslen] = tab
            self.raiseTab(id)


    def raiseTab(self, tabid):
        with open(os.getcwd() + '/../PlaylistListener/CurrentSongs.json') as current_songs:
            c_songs = json.load(current_songs)

        print(tabid)
        if self.curtab!= None and self.curtab != tabid and len(self.tabs)>1:
            try:
                #webbrowser.open(c_songs[tabid]['link'])
                webbrowser.open_new('http://youtube.com')
            except:
                pass



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Playlist Scraper')
    root.geometry("1920x1080+300+300")
    t = GUIPopulator(root)

    with open(os.getcwd() + '/../PlaylistListener/CurrentSongs.json') as current_songs:
        c_songs = json.load(current_songs)

    for song in c_songs:
            t.addTab(song)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example of JSON file provided:

```
{
  "F\u00d8RD - Shadows (feat. Samsaruh)": {
    "page_title": "youtube",
    "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=CNiV6Pne50U&index=32&list=PLkx04k4VGz1tH_pnRl_5xBU1BLE3PYuzd",
    "id": "CNiV6Pne50U",
    "channel": "youtube.com/watch?v=CNiV6Pne50U&index=32&list=PLkx04k4VGz1tH_pnRl_5xBU1BLE3PYuzd",
    "image_path": [
      "http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/CNiV6Pne50U/hqdefault.jpg",
      "CNiV6Pne50U.jpg"
    ]
  },
  "Katelyn Tarver - You Don't Know (tof\u00fb remix)": {
    "page_title": "youtube",
    "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=7pPNv38JzD4&index=43&list=PLkx04k4VGz1tH_pnRl_5xBU1BLE3PYuzd",
    "id": "7pPNv38JzD4",
    "channel": "youtube.com/watch?v=7pPNv38JzD4&index=43&list=PLkx04k4VGz1tH_pnRl_5xBU1BLE3PYuzd",
    "image_path": [
      "http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/7pPNv38JzD4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "7pPNv38JzD4.jpg"
    ]
  },
  "Illenium - Crawl Outta Love (feat. Annika Wells)": {
    "page_title": "youtube",
    "link": "youtube.com/watch?v=GprXUDZrdT4&index=7&list=PLkx04k4VGz1tH_pnRl_5xBU1BLE3PYuzd",
    "id": "GprXUDZrdT4",
    "channel": "youtube.com/watch?v=GprXUDZrdT4&index=7&list=PLkx04k4VGz1tH_pnRl_5xBU1BLE3PYuzd",
    "image_path": [
      "http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/GprXUDZrdT4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "GprXUDZrdT4.jpg"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code that appears to be irrelevant to the question being asked. Please try to condense this down to a [mcve] which doesn't depend on external data files.

Comment: instead of creating the toplevel frame every time your mouse enters the button field you should probably create the frame in your `__init__` section and then `on_entry` would place the frame with the grid manager and then forget the grid on leave. Or you can even use the `tkraise()` method to raise or lower the toplevel as needed.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. As long as my mouse cursor remains inside a button, the `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events don't fire. They only fire when I actually leave the window. Just to be clear: are you stating that if you move the mouse _without leaving the boundary of a button_, you're seeing the `<Leave>` event fire?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yep. Do you think it has something to do with OS X? I know that a few button features do not work with OS X compared to other operating systems.

Comment: On your machine, is the toplevel popping up over the button?

Comment: @BryanOakley It was not. It originally would open in the top left of the frame and then every mouse movement within a button would cause it to be destroyed and be reopened maybe a millimeter down diagonally to the right. So it would cascade down hundreds of times if I moved my mouse around. I'm going to try to get Sierra's option implemented.

Comment: @BryanOakley Granted, now that you mentioned that I and think about it. I honestly believe the newly opened window took focus if I moved my mouse around. When I changed it to what I have now, I have to manually click on the frame to have any new action happen by hovering over the buttons. So it seems to take focus and I believe that is the issue.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Thank you for your response. I'm trying to go with your solution right now and it's already looking better. Only problem is an issue I was running into earlier with having the new frame created and placed in the grid removed any buttons in the same rows as it even though it's nowhere near those buttons.

Comment: is this the toplevel frame you are talking about? What frame is causing this issue. What does this frame do. You may benefit from creating a shorter version of your code or at least remove the section that pulls in a json file and instead give us a list or dict that represents this json file with a few examples in it. This will allow us to test what is going on and work on a solution. This is why we ask for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Excess code or code that relies on external files that we do not have makes troubleshooting difficult

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Sorry about this. Pretty new to using stackoverflow. I added a few examples of what is provided in the json file.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I have come up with some code I think you can use or is what you are looking for.

I have changes a few things and add some others.

1st we needed to create a place holder for the top window that we can use later in the code. So in the `__init__` section of `GUIPopulatior` add `self.image_window = None`. We will talk about this part soon.

next I created the image path as a class attribute on `init` this can be changed later with update if need be.

next I added a `bind()` to the `init` that will help us keep the `self.image_window` placed in the correct location even if we move the root window. so we add `self.parent.bind("<Configure>", self.move_me)` to the `__init__` section as well.

next we create the method `move_me` that we just created a bind for.
the way it is written it will only take effect if `self.image_window` is not equal to `None` this should prevent any errors while `self.image_window` is being used however I have not created the error handling to deal with what happens after the toplevel window is closed by the user. Its not difficult but I wanted to answer for the main issue at hand.

Here is the `move_me` method:

```
def move_me(self, event):
    if self.image_window != None:
        h = self.parent.winfo_height() # gets the height of the window in pixels
        w = self.parent.winfo_width() # gets the width of the window in pixels

        # gets the placement of the root window then uses height and width to
        # calculate where to place the window to keep it at the bottom right.
        self.image_window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(self.parent.winfo_x() + w - 250,
                                                   self.parent.winfo_y() + h - 250))
```

next we need to modify the `on_enter` method to create the toplevel window if out class attribute `self.image_window` is equal to `None` if it is not equal to `None` then we can use the else portion of the if statement to just update the image.

Here is the modified `on_enter` method:

```
def on_enter(self, event):

    if self.image_window == None:
        self.image_window = Toplevel(self)
        #this keeps the toplevel window on top of the program
        self.image_window.attributes("-topmost", True)

        h = self.parent.winfo_height()
        w = self.parent.winfo_width()
        self.image_window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(self.parent.winfo_x() + w - 250,
                                                   self.parent.winfo_y() + h - 250))
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.img_path)
        self.image_window.title("Preview")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.image_window, width=200, height=200)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canv_image = self.canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=self.img)

    else:
        self.img = PhotoImage(file= self.img_path)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canv_image, image = self.img)
```

all that being said there are some other issues with your code that need to be addressed however this answer should point you in the right direction.

Below is a section of your code you need to replace:

```
class GUIPopulator(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.configure(bg='PeachPuff2')
        self.columnconfigure(20, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(30, weight=1)
        self.curtab = None
        self.tabs = {}
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.column = 0
        self.row = 0

    def on_enter(self, event):

        self.image_window = Toplevel(self)
        self.img_path = os.getcwd() + '/Rotating_earth_(large).gif'
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.img_path)

        #self.image_window.minsize(width=200, height=250)
        self.image_window.title("Preview")
        canvas = Canvas(self.image_window, width=200, height=200)
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=self.img)
    #def on_leave(self, enter):
```

With this:

```
class GUIPopulator(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.configure(bg='PeachPuff2')
        self.columnconfigure(20, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(30, weight=1)
        self.curtab = None
        self.image_window = None
        self.img_path = os.getcwd() + '/Rotating_earth_(large).gif'
        self.tabs = {}
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.parent.bind("<Configure>", self.move_me)
        self.column = 0
        self.row = 0

    def move_me(self, event):
        if self.image_window != None:
            h = self.parent.winfo_height()
            w = self.parent.winfo_width()
            self.image_window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(self.parent.winfo_x() + w - 250,
                                                       self.parent.winfo_y() + h - 250))

    def on_enter(self, event):

        if self.image_window == None:
            self.image_window = Toplevel(self)
            self.image_window.attributes("-topmost", True)

            h = self.parent.winfo_height()
            w = self.parent.winfo_width()
            self.image_window.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(self.parent.winfo_x() + w - 250,
                                                       self.parent.winfo_y() + h - 250))
            self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.img_path)
            self.image_window.title("Preview")
            self.canvas = Canvas(self.image_window, width=200, height=200)
            self.canvas.pack()
            self.canv_image = self.canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=self.img)

        else:
            self.img = PhotoImage(file= self.img_path)
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canv_image, image = self.img)
```